Issue with Google Authentication using AWS Cognito in Next.js App
I'm working on a Next.js application and trying to authenticate users with Google using AWS Cognito. The button is supposed to handle the authentication like this:
 'use client'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { signInWithRedirect, signOut, getCurrentUser, AuthUser } from 'aws-amplify/auth'
import { Hub } from 'aws-amplify/utils'
import { Separator } from '../separator'
import { Button } from '../button'

export default function GoogleLogin({ label }: { label: string }) {
    const [user, setUser] = useState<AuthUser | null>(null)
    const [error, setError] = useState<unknown>(null)
    const [customState, setCustomState] = useState<string | null>(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = Hub.listen('auth', ({ payload }) => {
            switch (payload.event) {
                case 'signInWithRedirect':
                    getUser()
                    break
                case 'signInWithRedirect_failure':
                    setError('An error has occurred during the OAuth flow.')
                    console.error('OAuth flow error:', payload.data)
                    break
                case 'customOAuthState':
                    setCustomState(payload.data)
                    break
                default:
                    console.warn(`Unhandled auth event: ${payload.event}`)
                    break
            }
        })

        getUser()

        return () => unsubscribe()
    }, [])

    const getUser = async (): Promise<void> => {
        try {
            const currentUser = await getCurrentUser()
            setUser(currentUser)
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching current user:', error)
            setError('Not signed in')
        }
    }

    const signInWithGoogle = async () => {
        try {
            console.log('paso')
            const signin = signInWithRedirect({
                provider: 'Google',
            })
            console.log(signin)
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error signing in with Google:', error)
            setError(error)
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Button onClick={() => signInWithRedirect()}>Sign in with Google</Button>
            <div className='flex flex-row justify-center items-center my-6'>
                <div className='flex-grow'>
                    <Separator />
                </div>
                <div className='text-gray-400 text-l mx-2'>or</div>
                <div className='flex-grow'>
                    <Separator />
                </div>
            </div>
            <Button onClick={() => signOut()}>Sign Out</Button>
            <div>{user?.username}</div>
            <div>{customState}</div>
        </div>
    )
}

And my Amplify Cognito configuration is as follows:
'use client'
import { Amplify, type ResourcesConfig } from 'aws-amplify'

export const authConfig: ResourcesConfig['Auth'] = {
    Cognito: {
        userPoolId: String(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_USER_POOL_ID),
        userPoolClientId: String(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_USER_POOL_CLIENT_ID),
        loginWith: {
            oauth: {
                domain: String(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_OAUTH_DOMAIN),
                scopes: ['profile', 'email', 'openid'],
                redirectSignIn: [String(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_OAUTH_REDIRECT_SIGN_IN)],
                redirectSignOut: [String(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_OAUTH_REDIRECT_SIGN_OUT)],
                responseType: 'code',
            },
        },
    },
}

Amplify.configure(
    {
        Auth: authConfig,
    },
    { ssr: true }
)

export default function ConfigureAmplifyClientSide() {
    return null
} 

However, when I click the button, it redirects me to a non-existent error page:

https://https//chatinmobiliario.auth.us-east-2.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize?redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fdashboard&response_type=token&client_id=xxxxxx&identity_provider=Google&scope=email%20profile%20openid&state=xxxxxx

That have the following error:

This site can’t be reachedCheck if there is a typo in https.DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Does anyone know what might be causing this issue or how to fix it? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

My mistake was including the protocol (https:// or http://) in the domain configuration. Ensure that NEXT_PUBLIC_OAUTH_DOMAIN contains only the domain name without any protocol.
Once I corrected this, the issue was resolved.
